# How to switch off audio output ios?

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

Is it possible to switch off audio output on device?

I need route the sound to phone's speaker when headphones are connected.

I need to connect some device via audio output(like connect headphones) but if i connected it the voice on ios device is blocked. I want turn off audio output and turn on when i need use this device.

Comment: what is the app trying to do?  Why cant you play the audio through the headphones?

Comment: Ah, now i understand - you should add that to the question, I dont have the answer.  But yes, I am sure if your are adding your own headphone device, and you still want to use the mic/speaker, there is probably a way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you can do this. Because apple is very strict and stick with their functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This goes against Apple's Human Interface Guidelines. If you read the section on Technology usage you find a section labelled Sound. It describes the expected behaviour when using headphones:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/TechnologyUsage/TechnologyUsage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH18-SW3

Comment: Now that he added the comment to the question, I think this might not apply right?  Since its not headphones he is connecting but a device. (im guessing, like a jawbone up.)